# Collection_select redirecting with parameters with the help of javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to make a redirect the user to a route 'attendance/:domain' when the option from the dropdown that I made changes. I am doing this using javascript. Earlier implementations like: `window.location = "<%= url_for(:controller => 'attendance', :action => 'index') %>?" + id;` just add the id to the earlier link so if I had `'attendance/2'` it would become `'attendance/23'` instead of `'attendance/3'` . So I am trying to use the path provided by ruby like so:

config.rb:

```
get 'attendance/:domain', to: 'attendance#index', as: 'attendance_domain'
```

view:

```
<div class="form-group col-lg-3 col-md-5 ">
        <%= label_tag(:domain, "Domeniu", class: "control-label") %>
        <%= collection_select(nil, :id, @domains, :id, :complete_name, {selected: -1}, {:onchange=> "redirectToIndex(this.value)",:selected => params[:domain],class: "form-control"}) %>
    </div>
```

javascript in view:

```
function redirectToIndex(trainerId){
     window.location ="<%= url_for(attendance_domain_path(" + trainerId + ")) %>";
  }
```

In this implementation the link that I am redirected to is : `http://localhost:3000/attendance/ + trainerId +` which is not what I wanted. Instead of trainerId it should be the value of that variable.  Any tips please ?
In the end my question is : How can I redirect with parameters using collection_select. This dropdown will be available on the same page so the parameters need to change accordingly not like in the situation described above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass the full url to `redirectToIndex()` from `collection_select` via `proc`. Try this in view:

```
<%= collection_select(nil, :id, @domains, -> (d) {attendance_domain_path d},
  :complete_name, {selected: -1}, {:onchange=> "redirectToIndex(this.value)",
  :selected => params[:domain],class: "form-control"}) %>
```

In JS:

```
function redirectToIndex(val){
 window.location = val;
```

}

Comment: -> (d) {url_for d} , i replace d in this with the rails path ?

Comment: `-> (d) {url_for d}` is a `lambda`. Rails will call it for each item in `@domains` and the select value will contain the full url, not only the `id`. Just try the code and take a look at the produced HTML.

Comment: i get something like syntax error, unexpected tLPAREN_ARG, expecting keyword_do_LAMBDA or tLAMBEG :D . Give me a few minutes to try to fix this

Comment: What's your Ruby and Rails version?

Comment: gem 'rails', '4.0.4' and ruby something like 2.2.0

Comment: Try `Proc.new {|d| url_for d}` instead of `-> (d) {url_for d}`. Maybe it's some old Ruby without lambdas. On my 2.2.0 it works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75573/discussion-between-oleg-k-and-lucian-tarna).

Answer (score 1):

You fundamentally can't do this - you can't call a ruby function, evaluated serverside with a parameter known only to your javascript at page display time (unless of course you make an Ajax request).

The [js-routes](https://github.com/railsware/js-routes) gem uses your routes file to create javascript implementations of all the named routes: you'd be able to do

```
Routes.attendance_domain_path(id)
```

In your javascript. If it's just the one route then that might be a bit overkill.

Comment: It's for 5 routes I think :D but I guess the overkill is still there

Comment: yes your solution works perfectly , but so does Oleg's and he posted first , i am sorry i can't check yours also sadly